# Resizing the window breaks float behavior when using media queries?

Tags: css, css-float, media-queries, window-resize

I have a site that I'm working that has navigation bar with secondary block-level elements (images in my case) inside the `<a>` tags which respond to the window size by either floating or not floating. As long as a user never resizes their browser window after loading the page, the issue would never occur, but it appears as though if the page is stretched wide, and then scaled down without reloading the page, the float style attached to the main CSS declaration (not inside a @media query) fails to activate.

http://jsfiddle.net/MrPickle/ace1rtrq/

Here's an example the behavior that I'm seeing (with the same css code I'm using for layout). If you play with the size of the result panel, you can see what I'm talking about.

I know that I could use javascript to monitor the width of the page and add or remove a `.left` class to the inner element as needed, but I don't think that's the most elegant solution possible. Has anyone ever run into this kind of an issue?

Comment: that media query is working on my end: above 600px it will kick in and bellow that its ignored; what is your expected behavior?

Comment: upon returning below 600px, the span element should rise up to be in line with main link text, floated to the left of the inside of the element.

Comment: the smaller width screen should read "BarFoo" and the wider screen width should read out like 

"Foo
Bar"